# Android Studio app icon for US and UK

Tags: android, localization

I know i can different app icons for different languages by putting the icons in the folders drawable-en-hdpi, drawable-fr-hdpi etc. But can I have an icon for the UK and an icon for the US?

Comment: Is your problem solved?

Answer (score 3):

Try `drawable-en-rUS` and `drawable-en-rGB`

With sizes `drawable-en-rUS-hdpi`

Answer (score 2):

For US: drawable-en-rUS-hdpi

For UK: drawable-en-rGB-hdpi